# Alguém pode me dizer onde esta o erro por favor? Está dando "invalid syntax"

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
n = str(input("Informe o nome do aluno: ")

m = int(input("Informe o numero da matricula do aluno: ")

print("O nome do aluno é: %s, o numero da matricula é: %d" %(n,m))
```

Comment: Faltam alguns `)` no final da 1 e 2 linha.

Comment: `m = int(input("Informe o numero da matricula do aluno: ")` está faltando fechar o final desta linha.

Comment: Favor detalhar mais sua pergunta, para obter uma melhor resposta.

Comment: Falta de atenção, jovem. É  uma boa ideia começar a usar o Sublime Text com um Python Linter, ou então alguma outra ide que mostre erros de sintaxe.

Comment: Obrigado, foi vacilo meu :T

Comment: Eu tentei instalar o eclipse mas tava dando erro aqui, vou tentar outra ide

Answer (score 1):

Tente assim:

```
n = str(input("Informe o nome do aluno: "))
m = int(input("Informe o numero da matricula do aluno: "))
print("O nome do aluno é: %s, o numero da matricula é: %d" % (n,m))
```

Comment: Hahaha maldito parênteses

Comment: @taynan Deu certo?

Comment: Pior que não, agora esta dando erro na ultima linha :(

Comment: Agora consegui, muito obrigado :)